# database.Stateful Interface is not working as expected

Tags: apex, batch

```
global class batchForStateful implements Database.Batchable<Sobject>,Database.Stateful{
    global static list<cust__c> soList=new list<cust__c>();
    global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){}

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        Util.staticMethod();
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        system.debug('--->asitm9'+soList.size());
        //returning zero;
    }
}

class Util{
    static void staticMethod(){
    if(batchForStateful.soList==null){
        batchForStateful.soList=new list<cust__c>();
    }
    batchForStateful.soList.add(new cust__c() );
    }
}
```

Debug statement should print size greater than zero, but why it is printing zero all the time??

Comment: Try remove "static" from the `soList` declaration

Comment: @Bachovski post it as answer! http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm: "When using Database.Stateful, only instance member variables retain their values between transactions. Static member variables don’t and are reset between transactions".

Answer (score 11):

All your variables need to be instance variables - static ones reset for each execute method. Remove "static" from your variable declaration.

From the documentation:

> If you specify Database.Stateful in the class definition, you can
>   maintain state across these transactions. When using
>   Database.Stateful, only instance member variables retain their values
>   between transactions. Static member variables don’t and are reset
>   between transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Static values are available per transaction, you need something for whole operation.
As @Bachovski posted, just remove static from variable declaration.